# Marketing Cloud - Payment Confirmation Email With Multiple Line Items - Instant Sending Options

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sql, triggered-send, entry-criteria

looking for some ways forward with this dilemma I have.

We're implementing an payment confirmation email to send in Journey Builder. The order confirmation contains data from multiple objects in Salesforce and there is a chance that some objects do not appear/are not relevant for the payment confirmation.

Currently the data structure looks like this from Salesforce (items that are capitalised are objects) -
Order will always contain a Deal, Account and Line Items.
The Line Items may or may not have Add-Ons and/or Sub-Options.
The Order might vary in Passengers and the number of Payment Transactions.

The dilemma is - I can pull this via SQL, but considering this is an payment confirmation, the ideal scenario is that the email is triggered when an payment is received. However due to the objects the way they are positioned, a triggered send cannot reach all the objects when selecting entry data.

Are there any alternative solutions to explore in order to be able to fulfil this requirement? Whether it's a Marketing Cloud based solution to be able to instantly pull all this relevant data or a Salesforce solution to allow Marketing Cloud to see and send all this data, that'd be great.

I appreciate the assistance, and my newness at exploring these solutions.

Comment: I will recommend you taking a look at [RetrieveSalesforceObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/retrievesalesforceobjects.html) Ampscript function.

Comment: How about not dealing with data sync at all? MC has APIs, the APIs can be called from Sales Cloud/Service Cloud.